# Audio input prompt not updated

Tags: drivers, 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, input-devices

I am currently running 14.04 on a dell xps 13. I have installed some of the drivers from the driver [support pack](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/xps-13-9333?driverId=4NTWR&osCode=1204A&fileId=3322730329&languageCode=EN&categoryId=CS). However, these drivers were created for 12.04. The problem I am getting is that the audio input prompt no longer shows the the headset option.
I have tried reinstalling the ALSA sound drivers as well as PulseAudio. I even reinstalled the kernel. The prompt remains the same. Any ideas?
[image: Img]

Comment: is sound coming out of headset?

Comment: Yes, it detects the headset as headphones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

un-install the following using a package manager:

- `oem-pulseaudio-alsamixer-control-files_0.2_all.deb`
- `oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-quantal-dkms_0.201308192259~precise1_all.deb`

Then

```
apt-get remove --purge dkms
apt-get install dkms

apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
apt-get install pulseaudio
```

restart

I also uninstalled the other packages found in the [support pack](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/xps-13-9333?driverId=4NTWR&osCode=1204A&fileId=3322730329&languageCode=EN&categoryId=CS"rel="nofollow")